# Method repetition using overloading

Tags: java

How i could refactor "method" in order to not repeating code? It basically does the same thing for pause, resume and stop. At the moment I'm using a method overloading with boolean, so not the best idea. I don't know what to search for, so give me tips

```
private static void method(final boolean pause, final boolean resume, final boolean stop) {
    planes.forEach(plane -> {
        if (pause) {
            if (plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation() != null) {
                plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation().pause();
            }
            if (plane.getLandingAnimation() != null) {
                plane.getLandingAnimation().pause();
            }
            if (plane.getRandomTransition() != null) {
                plane.getRandomTransition().pause();
            }
        } else if (resume) {
            if (plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation() != null && plane.getStatusMovementAnimation().equals("PAUSED")) {
                plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation().play();
            }
            if (plane.getLandingAnimation() != null && plane.getStatusMovementAnimation().equals("PAUSED")) {
                plane.getLandingAnimation().play();
            }
            if (plane.getRandomTransition() != null && plane.getStatusMovementAnimation().equals("PAUSED")) {
                plane.getRandomTransition().play();
            }
        } else if (stop) {
            if (plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation() != null) {
                plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation().stop();
            }
            if (plane.getLandingAnimation() != null) {
                plane.getLandingAnimation().stop();
            }
            if (plane.getRandomTransition() != null) {
                plane.getRandomTransition().stop();
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void pause() {
    method(true, false, false);
}

public static void resume() {
    method(false, true, false);
}

public static void stop() {
    method(false, false, true);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to change the Plane class? Can you provide the relevant parts of the definition in the question? What types are returned by the methods you call here? Can you change that type?

Comment: Is it possible that the plane has multiple non-null animations at the same time? Does pausing, playing or stopping one animation affect the conditions checked for in the other branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be more readable with the logic for each command in its own separate method. The way this is written now, with everything in the method named `method`, makes it harder to understand the logic for each command, while not removing much duplication (only the `planes.foreach` part). It's also possible to invoke it in ways that don't make sense, such as passing multiple `true` parameters. So, as a first step of a multi-step refactoring process, I would extract the logic back into the individual methods:

```
public static void pause() {
    planes.forEach(plane -> {
        if (plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation() != null) {
            plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation().pause();
        }
        if (plane.getLandingAnimation() != null) {
            plane.getLandingAnimation().pause();
        }
        if (plane.getRandomTransition() != null) {
            plane.getRandomTransition().pause();
        }
    });
}

public static void resume() {
    planes.forEach(plane -> {
        if (plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation() != null && plane.getStatusMovementAnimation().equals("PAUSED")) {
            plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation().play();
        }
        if (plane.getLandingAnimation() != null && plane.getStatusMovementAnimation().equals("PAUSED")) {
            plane.getLandingAnimation().play();
        }
        if (plane.getRandomTransition() != null && plane.getStatusMovementAnimation().equals("PAUSED")) {
            plane.getRandomTransition().play();
        }
    });
}

public static void stop() {
    planes.forEach(plane -> {
        if (plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation() != null) {
            plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation().stop();
        }
        if (plane.getLandingAnimation() != null) {
            plane.getLandingAnimation().stop();
        }
        if (plane.getRandomTransition() != null) {
            plane.getRandomTransition().stop();
        }
    });
}
```

Next, if the `Plane` class is able to be changed, I would encapsulate the logic for each of these commands within that class. This way, callers don't need to know about the internal details of each animation for a plane:

```
public static void pause() {
    planes.forEach(Plane::pause);
}

public static void resume() {
    planes.forEach(Plane::resume);
}

public static void stop() {
    planes.forEach(Plane::stop);
}

class Plane {
    public void pause() {
        if (getPlaneMovementAnimation() != null) {
            getPlaneMovementAnimation().pause();
        }
        if (getLandingAnimation() != null) {
            getLandingAnimation().pause();
        }
        if (getRandomTransition() != null) {
            getRandomTransition().pause();
        }

    }

    public void resume() {
        if (getPlaneMovementAnimation() != null && getStatusMovementAnimation().equals("PAUSED")) {
            getPlaneMovementAnimation().play();
        }
        if (getLandingAnimation() != null && getStatusMovementAnimation().equals("PAUSED")) {
            getLandingAnimation().play();
        }
        if (getRandomTransition() != null && getStatusMovementAnimation().equals("PAUSED")) {
            getRandomTransition().play();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (getPlaneMovementAnimation() != null) {
            getPlaneMovementAnimation().stop();
        }
        if (getLandingAnimation() != null) {
            getLandingAnimation().stop();
        }
        if (getRandomTransition() != null) {
            getRandomTransition().stop();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

If you're not familiar with the syntax, `Plane::pause` and the others like  it are shortcuts for lambda expressions called [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). `Plane::pause` is identical to `plane -> plane.pause()`.

Of course, this only moves the duplication into `Plane`, so let's keep going. The structure of the `resume` method is a little different than the others, because it's checking `getStatusMovementAnimation().equals("PAUSED")` in each `if` statement. We can extract that check to an outer `if`, since it's the same for each one:

```
    public void resume() {
        if (getStatusMovementAnimation().equals("PAUSED")) {
            if (getPlaneMovementAnimation() != null) {
                getPlaneMovementAnimation().play();
            }
            if (getLandingAnimation() != null) {
                getLandingAnimation().play();
            }
            if (getRandomTransition() != null) {
                getRandomTransition().play();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the structure for each method is almost identical. Assuming that `getPlaneMovementAnimation()`, `getLandingAnimation()`, and `getRandomTransition()` all return the same type (I'll call it `Animation`), we can extract a method that returns a collection of non-`null` animations for the plane:

```
class Plane {
    private Collection<Animation> getActiveAnimations() {
        Collection<Animation> activeAnimations = new HashSet<>();
        if (getPlaneMovementAnimation() != null) {
            activeAnimations.add(getPlaneMovementAnimation());
        }
        if (getLandingAnimation() != null) {
            activeAnimations.add(getLandingAnimation());
        }
        if (getRandomTransition() != null) {
            activeAnimations.add(getRandomTransition());
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(activeAnimations);
    }

    public void pause() {
        getActiveAnimations().forEach(Animation::pause);
    }

    public void resume() {
        if (getStatusMovementAnimation().equals("PAUSED")) {
            getActiveAnimations().forEach(Animation::play);
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        getActiveAnimations().forEach(Animation::stop);
    }
```

Now, there's hardly any duplication. Only the `getActiveAnimations().forEach` and `planes.forEach` calls. Personally, I don't think it's worth trying to remove that duplication, since it's just a single call in each place. If you really wanted to, though, you could extract `forEachPlane` and `forEachAnimation` methods like this:

```
private static void forEachPlane(Consumer<Plane> action) {
    planes.forEach(action);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code I use to call a method by its name, then you can use switch/if on the method names

Also to decrease your code size you can try the following:
Use one method to invoke pause/resume/stop with a string parameter ie.

```
handle_method("pause");
```

then that method you can use like:

```
  public static void handle_method(String play_resume_or_stop)
    {
        try {
        Class<?> methods_in_class = Class.forName("com.xxx.xxx.PlaneStuff"); // convert string classname to class
        Object methods = methods_in_class.newInstance(); // get all methods in your class

        if (plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation() != null)
        {
            String methodNameIWant = "plane.getPlaneMovementAnimation()." + play_resume_or_stop; // your method name
            Method myMethod = methods.getClass().getMethod(methodNameIWant);
            myMethod.invoke(methods); // invoke your method
        }
        if (plane.getLandingAnimation() != null)
        {
            String methodNameIWant = "plane.getLandingAnimation()." + play_resume_or_stop;
            Method myMethod = methods.getClass().getMethod(methodNameIWant);
            myMethod.invoke(methods); // invoke your method
        }
        if (plane.getRandomTransition() != null)
        {
            String methodNameIWant = "plane.getRandomTransition()." + play_resume_or_stop;
            Method myMethod = methods.getClass().getMethod(methodNameIWant);
            myMethod.invoke(methods); // invoke your method
        }
        }catch (Exception allExpections){}

    }
```